# Issue: "Local Area Connection doesn't have a valid IP configuration."

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, ip, network-adapter

Windows 7. Small network, two PCs connected to Asus router, laptop have wireless internet connection, and desktop PC have wired connection. 
Desktop have 2 network adaptors on board. One as part of the system board, the other just happened "to be there", but I never touched it, as all worked fine.
Today I turned on desktop PC and find internet connection missing, network icon show no connection. I tried fix problem use built-in tools, but result always is "Local Area Connection doesn't have a valid IP configuration."  Laptop that have wireless connection works OK, router configuration show only one local IP (notebook) is present, but the it show two IPs, second device with local IP is unknown, its not a desktop PC.
T I tried run a lot of netsh commands from the cmd prompt(as Admin), but this not help:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipcnfig /registerdns
```

The last 3 commands not work, since desktop PC have no ip assigned.
I also tried run `sfc /scannow` command, but it didn't find any errors.

I suspect this issue might be somehow linked to Avast antivurus, its VPN component or firewall, that can be enabled/disabled, I tried to disable it, but not help. It looks that desktop PC couldn't get a address response from a router's DHCP server.

EDIT: `ipconfig /all` output

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : B-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8001/8003/8010 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-13-D4-51-7C-94
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::95b0:b1cf:81c4:bc5b%12 (Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . . 169.254.103.162 (Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234886100
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-0E-3C-FE-00-13-D4-51-7C-94

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: If you suspect the Avast software is to blame, have you tried to uninstall it, to confirm that is indeed the case?

Comment: I just uninstalled that VPN component, also tried to disable brandmauer. Laptop also have Avast installed, and there is no issues.

Comment: I have no idea what brandmauer is.  What english word are you looking to use?

Comment: I mean firewall.

Comment: provide us the output of `ipconfig /all `

Comment: See edited post. So problem is that desktop PC couldn't get the address response from a router's DHCP server.